# How to add php file in wordpress site?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new in wordpress.
I have created the xml to csv convertor in php.
i have two file index.php and convertxc.php

my issue is i want to implement those file in our wordpress site 
please help how to include those file...

Comment: hammm. Very difficult work. @ankit gupta :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can watch this.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6-ivr_ECyXY how add pages on wordpress site